# addEventListener on change that can Access a Method in an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a tough one. I need to add an event listener that on change a bunch of validation logic with other fields needs to happen. This is a pure JS solution. Let me show you what I have right now, and explain it.

```
        var RowsArray = [];
        var TrRow = function(valid,txt,dd){
            this.validateField = valid ;
            this.txtValue = txt;
            this.ddValue = dd;

            this.validate = function () { 
            //validation logic that accesses the nodes validateField, txtValue. etc 
            };
        };
```

Each `TrRow` set will go into `RowsArray`. Each row contains a text box, dropdown list and many more, this code is shortened for brevity. Note that this `validate` function accesses the nodes from the properties and goes through a lot of logic.

So onload I have this map function

```
 Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gridview tr'), function(obj, index) {

            var validateField = obj.querySelector('td:first-child > span');
            var txtValue = obj.querySelector('.txt_value');
            var ddValue = obj.querySelector('.dd_value');
            var internal = new TrSet(validateField, txtValue, ddValue);

            internal.validate();
            RowsArray.push(internal);
        });
```

And I'm trying to do something like this.

```
    ...
    var ddValue = obj.querySelector('.dd_value');
    var internal = new TrSet(validateField, txtValue, ddValue);

    internal.validate();
    RowsArray.push(internal);

    ///below is what I'm trying to do
    ddValue.addEventListener('change', function() {
        runTheValidateFunctionThatRelatesToTheCorrectObject()
    });
    txtValue.addEventListener('keyup', function() { 
        runTheValidateFunctionThatRelatesToTheCorrectObject();
    });
});
```

If this works, and I think this is much better than the old jQuery way we had it, I could reduce the code count from 500 down to less than 50. This should be more efficient since it was jquery, and this code is not constantly climbing the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was almost there, in the home stretch. Since I have the index of the map function. That will always be the same index in the `RowsArray` So adding the event listener, and calling the correct function in the object is as easy as...

```
ddValue.addEventListener('change', function() {
        RowsArray[index].validate();
    });
    txtValue.addEventListener('keyup', function() { 
        RowsArray[index].validate();
    });
```